# scraping html data and parsing into list

Tags: android, python, html, parsing, scrape

I am writing an android app using python for android (sl4a) and what I want it to do is search a joke website and extract a joke. Then tell me that joke to wake me up. So far it saves the raw html source to a list but I need it to make a new list by saving the data between html tags then reading that data to me. Its the parser I can't get to work. Here's the code:

```
import android
droid = android.Android() 
import urllib 
current = 0
newlist = []

sock = urllib.urlopen("http://m.funtweets.com/random") 
htmlSource = sock.read() 
sock.close() 
rawhtml = []
rawhtml.append (htmlSource)

while current < len(rawhtml):
    while current != "<div class=":
        if [current] == "</b></a>":
            newlist.append (current)
            current += 1


print newlist
```

Comment: for scraping see [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: I don't know how to install beautiful soup module because I am using a scripting layer for android, not a typical python install.

Answer (score 0):

use this LIB for parsing HTML in android `http://jsoup.org/` its reach and widely accepted lib among developers its also available for python :)

Comment: After reading jsoup documentation a thousand times, I still can't get any code to do what I want. Any specific suggestions on how to use jsoup for this purpose?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do this:
[Code]
    import re 
    import urllib2

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.m.funtweets.com/random").read() 
user = re.compile(r'<span>@</span>(\w+)') 
text = re.compile(r"</b></a> (\w.*)") 
user_lst =[match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(user, page)] 
text_lst =[match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(text, page)] 
for _user, _text in zip(user_lst, text_lst):
    print '@{0}\n{1}\n'.format(_user,_text)
```

[/code]